# Pasting multiple lines into IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

Is there a way to paste a block of code into [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE)? Pasting line by line works, but sometimes I'd like to paste many lines at once. When I try, IDLE reads the first line and ignores the rest.

```
>>> a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

>>>
>>> a
1
>>> b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    b
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Probably not the most beautiful procedure, but this works:

```
cmds = '''
```

paste your commands, followed by `'''`:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
'''
```

Then `exec(cmds)` will execute them.

Or more directly,

```
exec('''
```

then paste your commands, followed by `''')`:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
''')
```

It's just a trick, maybe there's a more official, elegant way.

Comment: that works, but I was really hoping for something more elegant.  It's pretty common to paste a bunch of lines into IDLE.  Testing parts of code from an IDE or running stuff posted on SO or whatever.

Comment: Yes, I often ran into the same issue and asked myself the same question... Same happens when pasting indented part of code, "solved" by typing `if True:` then pasting the code. A bit of a dirty trick ;-)

Comment: using pyscripter.. copy code from anywhere say a function... and then right click in interpreter... choose "paste and execute". and this will work nicely for multiline paste.

Comment: Nice trick! To get rid of copied indentation one can use stdlib `textwrap.dedent(exec(cmds))`.

Answer (score 9):

[IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net) provides the PastePyShell.py extension for IDLE which allows pasting of multiple lines into the shell for execution.

Answer (score 6):

See this other post: [Python, writing multi line code in IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413637/python-writing-multi-line-code-in-idle)
You can use an editor (File > New File), write your lines of code there and use F5

Comment: That requires committing it to disk, an extra hassle (extra time, finding an appropriate place, inventing a name, getting rid of it later, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of RedGlyph, but with some automation using [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) (AHK):

```
; Python IDLE shell
#IfWinActive ahk_exe pythonw.exe

^+x::  ; IDLE - multiple commands paste
SoundBeep,1700, 150
send, ^{end}
var1 = cmds = '''
var2 := clipboard
var3 = %var1%%var2%
var4 = %var3%'''
msgbox,,, %var4%,2
clipboard = %var4%
send, ^{vk0x56}   ;send, ^v
send, {enter}
sleep, 1000
send, exec(cmds)
return
```

You need to install AutoHotkey to make this work.
After installing AutoHotkey, the above code sample must be saved in a file with extension AHK (e.g., *Idle.ahk*), and should be running always to enable the shortcut:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to make the string manipulation for you.