# Writing multi-line code in Python's IDLE application

Tags: python, python-idle

How do I write

```
   >>> x = int(raw_input("Please enter an integer: "))
    >>> if x < 0:
    ...      x = 0
    ...      print 'Negative changed to zero'
    ... elif x == 0:
    ...      print 'Zero'
    ... elif x == 1:
    ...      print 'Single'
    ... else:
    ...      print 'More'
    ...
```

This is in [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE). As soon as I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after writting first line, it executes the first line and I am not able to write the full code.

Comment: You don't have to execute it all in one go, if you do, then use a file for multiple runs or declare a function for a single run. Even if it executes earlier than you expected, you'll still have the entered value in the `x` variable.

Answer (score 14):

Try menu *File* → *New File* in the top menu. Then write your code in this window and run it by the <kbd>F5</kbd> key (or *Run* in the top menu).

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> takes you to next line without executing the current line.

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 8):

1. Use semicolons between lines
2. Try [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython)
3. Write it as a function, e.g.,

   ```
    def myfunc():
        x = int(raw_input("Please enter an integer: "))
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
            print 'Negative changed to zero'
        elif x == 0:print 'Zero'
        elif x == 1:print 'Single'
        else:print 'More'
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `exec` function along with multi-line strings (`"""`) worked well for my particular use case:

```py
exec("""for foo in bar:
  try:
    something()
  except:
    print('Failed')"""
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't write multi-line code in the Python console. You need a third-party application.

Comment: Leaving my prior misconception because nobody corrected me and it has been 8 years. Maybe it is correct and the new info I have is not correct?
To extend the statement to one or more lines we can use braces {}, parentheses (), square [], semi-colon “;”, and continuation character slash “\”. - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-multi-line-statements/

Answer (score 2):

If you do File --> New File, it should open a new savable window that you can write multiple lines and save as a .py file.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new file enables you to write your code in multiline in IDLE and before writing the code you need to save the file as *.py format. That's all.

Comment: But it isn't very interactive.