# How do I write more than one line of code in Python IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

When I press my <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it runs the code instead of allowing me to write another line of code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, writing multi line code in IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413637/python-writing-multi-line-code-in-idle)

Comment: See also *[Pasting multiple lines into IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615379/)*.

Comment: cont' - Though this question is ***not*** about pasting more than one line of code into IDLE at a time. In a way, it is the opposite (expectation of file-like behaviour, not interactive behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. But you can write loops functions this way. Create a new file in your IDE. Save that file and run your code.

Comment: so python idle only enables me to write one line?

Comment: What do you mean by *"loops functions"*? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61358415/edit) (change) your answer. But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a '' for continuing the code to multiple lines in the Python interpreter.

```
>>> x = 1;\
... print(x); \
... y=2; \
... print(y)
1
2
```