# Entering multiple lines into the Python shell

Tags: python, shell

In my educational book it says "You can only enter one line of code into the shell at once. You cannot copy and paste multiple lines."

But you can, so was it impossible in the past or do they mean "one statement"?

E.g. I can paste the following and it prints *I don't know!*

```
x=100

ENTER

if x == 10:
    print("10!")
elif x == 20:
    print("20!")
else:
    print("I don't know!")
```

Comment: You can *enter* as many lines as you like, but the REPL will execute the code one statement at a time.

Comment: You can paste multiple lines, but they'll all be executed individually.

Comment: Also worth noting, while it's terrible form, you can "separate" statements with a `;`, for example `import math; x = 100; print(math.sqrt(x))` all on one line.

Comment: There is a major difference in what you can do between the REPL and a script: the REPL does not allow blank lines in the middle of a multi-line statement.  For example, in a script you could put a blank line before the `elif` or `else` with no problem, but in the REPL the blank line would terminate the existing statement, and would result in a SyntaxError because `elif` or `else` cannot start a new statement.

Comment: Is `if x == 10:
    print("10!")` a statement?

Comment: Is the code after ENTER one statement?

Comment: Re *"You can only enter one line of code into the shell at once"*: Yes, that is true for [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) (but not for the regular Python shell). See e.g. *[Pasting multiple lines into IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615379/)* and *[Writing multi-line code in Python's IDLE application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413637/writing-multi-line-code-in-pythons-idle-application/)*.