# Weird variable multiple assignment python in IDLE

Tags: python, variables, python-idle

I'm really confused, I just wrote this

```
x = 0
y = 42

#Can also be written like this

x, y = 0, 42

print x
print y
```

And copy pasted it into IDLE to test it (I'm trying to relearn python along PHP) and then typed "x" and it returned 0. I type y and it gives me an error that it's not defined. When I run this normally though it works fine. What's going on?

Here is the exact error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    y
NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Comment: Works correctly for me in IDLE 2.7

Comment: You might want to look at [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net/) -- it handles this particular issue (at least for me on OS X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might have to do with posting multiple lines of code into IDLE. Take a look at the following:

[Pasting multiple lines into IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615379/pasting-multiple-lines-into-idle)

Hope this helps!