# loading python functions returns syntax error

Tags: python, function

I'm getting an error message quoting that I have a syntax error when trying to load my functions.
I can load them one at a time into the IDLE, but when pasting the full script, an error is returned. I believe its to do with the second function calling the first. To test this, the simple code below also returns this error :(.

```
def hello():
    print('Hello there!')

def boo():
    hello()
```

I'm unsure why this happens because the first function is defined before its called in the second. So it should be loaded in memory already shouldn't it?

Thanks for any help you can give. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615379/pasting-multiple-lines-into-idle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE interactive interpreter can only handle one task at once, you can't do more.

Save the script to a python file (`.py` extension), and run it.

From the command line:

```
$ cd /script_path
$ python script_name.py
```

Or if you want to run it in IDLE:

> Ctrl+N - Paste the code - Save - Press F5

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for that; that of course explains why. :).
Thank you for your help.